# How to solve and plot Definite Integral with Symbolic Limits

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, symbolic, integral-equations

I need to plot g1, g2, g3 and g4 expressions. To do that, I am trying to evaluate the double defined integral in the three expressions, however I am having issues because one of the integration limits (alpha) is function of w. The resultante error says:

NIntegrate::nlim: α = α is not a valid limit of integration.

The question here is how can I compute a definite integral if I have a symbolic limit? Is it possible to do that?

Otherwise, is there anothet way to calculate and plot these expressions solving the indefinite integral?

Thanks in advance.

```
d = 0.0254;
ad = 0.3;
a = ad*d;
young = 210 10^9;
iner = (Pi/64)*d^4;
ld = 24;
L = ld*d;
wcord = Sqrt[a*(d - a)];

α = a - (d/2) + Sqrt[((d/2)^2) - (w^2)];
αp = Sqrt[d^2 - (2*w)^2];
rα = α/αp;
F = Sqrt[(2*αp)/(Pi*α)*Tan[(Pi*α)/(2*αp)]]*((0.923 + 0.199*(1 - Sin[(Pi*[Alpha])/(2*αp)])^4)/Cos[(Pi*α)/(2*αp)]);

Fp = Sqrt[(2*αp)/(Pi*α)*Tan[(Pi*α)/(2*αp)]]*((0.752 + 2.02*rα + 0.37*(1 - Sin[(Pi*α)/(2*αp)])^3)/Cos[(Pi*α)/(2*αp)]);

flxbInt = L^3/(48*young*iner) ;

g1 = flxbInt + 2*(NIntegrate[((128*(L^2)*(αp^2))/(young*Pi*(d^8)))*α*F^2, {α, 0, α}, {w, 0, wcord}])      

g4 = flxbInt + 2*(NIntegrate[((512*(L^2)*(w^2))/(young*Pi*(d^8)))*α*Fp^2, {α, 0, α}, {w, 0, wcord}])     

g2 = g3 = 2*(NIntegrate[((256*(L^2)*αp*w)/(young*Pi*(d^8)))*α*F*Fp, {α, 0, α}, {w, 0, wcord}])
```

[image: code]

Comment: There is a type in the definition of `F`;  also, change the dummy integration variable.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way of tackling this problem is defining a unnesting the integrals, converting to functions, and using `NIntegrate`

As before:

```
d = 0.0254;
ad = 0.3;
a = ad*d;
young = 210 10^9;
iner = (Pi/64)*d^4;
ld = 24;
L = ld*d;
wcord = Sqrt[a*(d - a)];

\[Alpha] = a - (d/2) + Sqrt[((d/2)^2) - (w^2)];
\[Alpha]p = Sqrt[d^2 - (2*w)^2];
r\[Alpha] = \[Alpha]/\[Alpha]p;

F = Sqrt[(2*\[Alpha]p)/(Pi*\[Alpha])*Tan[(Pi*\[Alpha])/(2*\[Alpha]p)]]*((0.923 + 0.199*(1 - Sin[(Pi*\[Alpha])/(2*\[Alpha]p)])^4)/Cos[(Pi*\[Alpha])/(2*\[Alpha]p)]);
Fp = Sqrt[(2*\[Alpha]p)/(Pi*\[Alpha])*Tan[(Pi*\[Alpha])/(2*\[Alpha]p)]]*((0.752 + 2.02*r\[Alpha] + 0.37*(1 - Sin[(Pi*\[Alpha])/(2*\[Alpha]p)])^3)/Cos[(Pi*\[Alpha])/(2*\[Alpha]p)]);
flxbInt = L^3/(48*young*iner);
```

Now define

```
i1[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[k, {k, 0, z}];
```

Rewriting the integrals in terms of our new function `i1`

```
g1 = flxbInt + 2*(NIntegrate[((128*(L^2)*(\[Alpha]p^2))/(young*Pi*(d^8)))*i1[\[Alpha]]*F^2, {w, 0, wcord}])
g4 = flxbInt + 2*(NIntegrate[((512*(L^2)*(w^2))/(young*Pi*(d^8)))*i1[\[Alpha]]*Fp^2, {w, 0, wcord}])
g2 = g3 = 2*(NIntegrate[((256*(L^2)*\[Alpha]p*w)/(young*Pi*(d^8)))*i1[\[Alpha]]*F*Fp, {w, 0, wcord}])
```

Evaluating the integrals yields:

```
(*g1 = 1.20937*10^-6*)
(*g4 = 1.13447*10^-6*)
(*g2 = g3 = 4.88326*10^-8*)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful.

Comment: In case I need a symbolic expression for each variable g. Do you think there is some way to get it?

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to find an analytical expression for each integral. I would suggest sticking with numerics for this problem, though I don't want to close the door completely to the possibility that a solution exists.